# AS3 Update variable in root from mc

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This should be simple.
I want to play a movie clip on the stage 3 times and then go to my ending in flash.

I instantiate a variable on the main timeline at frame 1

```
var i:int = 0;
```

and on the last frame of the movie clip i want to iterate my variable

```
this.i += 1;
trace(this.i);
```

But my trace returns unassigned etc.
I seem to be using the wrong operator but nothing I've tried works.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exemplifies separation of concerns, such as decoupling code - however that aside, a trick some former AS2 developers have used in AS3 to replace global variables is attaching variables to root.

For example - on your main timeline actions, declare your variable attached to root:

**Main timeline**

```
MovieClip(root).myVar = 1;
```

Now from anywhere, such as your symbols, you may access the same object:

**MovieClip timeline**

```
MovieClip(root).myVar += 1;
trace(MovieClip(root).myVar);
```

As an alternative approach, it would be a better design pattern to define a main document class and use static variables:

```
public class Main {
    public static var myVar:uint = 1;
}
```

Then, you can access this static variable anywhere:

```
Main.myVar += 1;
trace(Main.myVar);
```

Comment: Your code: `MovieClip(root).myVar = 1;` is considered like an error by my Flash compiler. 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method MovieClip.

Comment: @helloflash What are you compiling with?  Try for yourself - [CC 2014 FLA](http://labs.jasonsturges.com/stack-overflow/examples/variable-in-root/variable-in-root.fla) at my [labs](http://labs.jasonsturges.com/stack-overflow/examples/variable-in-root/).  If `MovieClip` is undefined, import it: `import flash.display.MovieClip`

Answer (score 0):

**Your solution**

You can write on the main timeline:

```
var i:int = 1;
```

And on the last frame of your MovieClip:

```
if (MovieClip(parent).i++ == 3) stop();
```

**Another solution**

You can also count how many times your MovieClip has been played, using its properties [`currentFrame`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#currentFrame) and [`totalFrames`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#totalFrames). Simply write on the main timeline:

```
var i:int = 0;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, timesIPlayed);

function timesIPlayed(e:Event):void {
    if (myMovieClip.currentFrame == myMovieClip.totalFrames) i++;
    if (i == 3) {
        myMovieClip.stop();
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, timesIPlayed);
    }
}
```